# Why Can't Sympy Integrate 1/\sqrt{x^2+x}

Tags: python, sympy

I tried this:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.abc import x
sy.integrate(1/sy.sqrt(x**2+x),x)
```

But sympy simply returned a repeat of the integration instead of giving the result of it which SageMath would do.

This should be easy to integrate.

Comment: Would be good if you could show more of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening. If you knew `x` to be real and positive, you could try:

```py
import sympy as sy

x = sy.symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)
sol = sy.integrate(1/sy.sqrt(x**2+x), x)
print(sol)
print(sol.doit())
```

For some reason, this only gives a solution if you add `doit()`.

Output:

```
Integral(1/(sqrt(x)*sqrt(x + 1)), x)
2*acosh(sqrt(x + 1))
```